# Can Cramer's Rule really distinguish between infinite no. of solutions and no solution?

Tags: matrices, contest-math, determinant

[image]

This is a question which was asked in a high-school exam held in India(**JEE ADVANCED**). Going by Cramer's rule, for infinite solutions, I should get $D=D_1=D_2=D_3=0$ (where $D$ is the original determinant and $D_1, D_2, D_3$ are the respective coefficient determinants). Using these, I arrive at $\alpha^2$=1, so that $\alpha$=1,-1. But, $\alpha=1$ yields *no solution* here (if I write down the system of equations using $\alpha=1$). Why does it happen so? Is this a rare failure of Cramer's rule? How should we explain this unexpected result?

Comment: It is not really a failure of Cramer's rule because this usually assumes $D\ne 0$ giving a unique solution.

Comment: The determinant is $(\alpha^2-1)^2$ so you must have $\alpha = \pm 1$. If you choose $\alpha = 1$ then the right hand side would have to have all the same values. So just by elimination we have $\alpha = -1$ and so $1+ \alpha+\alpha^2 = 1$.

Comment: Cramer’s rule can’t distinguish between incompatible and underdetermined systems of more than two equations; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Incompatible_and_indeterminate_cases).

Comment: A valid way to distinguish the three cases $1)$ no solution $2)$ a unique solution $3)$ infinite many solutions is to determine the rank of $A$ and the rank of the matrix if we concatenate $A$ with $b$ (if $Ax=b$ is given). Then, we have case $1)$ if the ranks do not coincide , case $2)$ if the ranks coincide and are equal to the number of columns and $3)$ if the ranks coincide and are smaller than the number of columns.

Answer (score 3):

For Cramer's rule for 3 equations, if $D\ne 0$, then you have a single solution. IF $D=0$ and any one of $D_1, D_2, D_3$ is non-zero, then the system is inconsistent. If all of those are zero, you still have two possibilities, one where the system is indeterminate and one where the system is inconsistent.